# Flutter MySql1 Realtime data

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart, mysql-workbench

I can't make data run in Realtime which mean data that I want display always update if have change in database. right now I just can make data display if I push button to request data from MySQL workbench. I using MySQL1

Please help me almost a month I try to solve this problem T_T

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.